# How do I programmatically enable floating notifications and unlock screen notifications in Oreo?

Tags: java, android

I would like to enable all of the notification options, but I can't do it(see sreenshot). I installed telegram and all of the options for it are enabled by default. Why and how?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57dW1.jpg)

Currently I have this code:

```
NotificationManager notifManager=(NotificationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

    // Configure the notification channel.
    mChannel.setDescription("Common notifications");
    mChannel.enableLights(true);
    mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
    mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
    mChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    mChannel.enableVibration(true);
    notifManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
}
```

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setColor(color)
                .setTicker("")
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("ContextText")
                .setContentInfo("Info")
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
```

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(SOMEID, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Have you tested in other devices? I've tried your code on an emulated Pixel and it seemed to work correctly (the app's notification settings were all "on" by default). Also, is your channel using `IMPORTANCE_HIGH` since the beginning? Once the channel is created, you cannot modify its importance, so maybe the channel saved in your device isn't exactly the one you're using now in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested it on Xiaomi Redmi 6. I tried to reinstall app so I don't think IMPORTANCE_HIGH may affect such behavoir. Today I found this topic https://medium.com/mindorks/enable-background-services-in-chinese-roms-32e73dfba1a6 and it seems that chinese phones have selective restrictions considering some of the significant settings.

Comment: @RustamShafigullin Did you got any solution?

Comment: @AswathyKR See my comment above, I made a dialog directing a user to phone's notifications options ("Please check notifications options before continue")

Comment: Same here. When I install other apps they come with all permisions enabled by default. I supouse its my phone (redmi 9). I will made a dialog. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I add this permission to Android Manifest file. It worked for me.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

Comment: Tested this on a Xiaomi note 7 device, nothing changed. Sorry but this is not a solution.

Comment: Tested this on Xiaomi mi5 and floating head up notification were  enabled